pmax (pmin) na.rm not working - Problem with NA/NaN Argument
I am dealing with a problem related to the pmax (and the pmin) function. I know it is used to get rowwise max (min) values. And what I wanted to get are the max and min values so to set some columns to a new range that is balanced for my analysis. The a:g is the old range and e:g is the new range that I want to use and balance out. My dataframe is not exactly the same (quite big actually), but for the sake of getting to the point, lets say the df is like this:
# Example df

ind <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c(2008,2012,2016,2020)
indiv <- rep(ind, times=4)
year <- rep(y, times=3)

a <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
b <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
c <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
d <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
e <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
f <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
g <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)

df_data <- data.frame(indiv,year,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

# Code for max min and new range

newdf <- df_data %>% 
  mutate(Oldmax = pmax(a:g,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Oldmin = pmin(a:g,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Newmax = pmax(e:g,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Newmin = pmin(e:g,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Oldrange = Oldmax-Oldmin) %>% 
  mutate(Newrange = Newmax-Newmin) %>% 
  mutate(across(e:g,
                (((~ .x - Oldmin) * Newrange) / Oldrange) + Newmin,
                .names = "{.col}_bal")
         )

The console tells me that there is a problem with the argument being NA, and I set na.rm to TRUE, but still face problems. Any further advise regarding pmax and rowwise functions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You have a couple of issues - 1) You can'tuse tidyselect expressions in functions that don't support them, so you need to use pick(a:g) not just a:g.  2) You need to use do.call() to pass a list as individual arguments to pmax(). 3) Mutate takes multiple expressions, you don't need to call it repeatedly for each transformation.  Your mutate call should look like mutate(Oldmax = do.call(pmax, c(pick(a:g), na.rm = TRUE)), Oldmin = do.call(pmin, c(pick(a:g), na.rm = TRUE)), ...).

Hey @Iroha, thank you so much for the comment. I have applied what you said and the first part worked out perfectly!! However, when using it for the across function, it did not work: mutate( do.call( across, c(pick(e:g) ), (((~ .x - Oldmin) * Newrange) / Oldrange) + Newmin, .names = "{.col}_bal" ) ). I do not understand why, it tells me that there is a problem not using the .names. Hope you know what is going on, because I certainly do not. Also, when I get the result I can post the answer so people do not do the same silly mistakes as I did hahahaha.

You don't need do.call() or pick() there, use across(e:g, ~ (((.x - Oldmin) * Newrange) / Oldrange) + Newmin, .names = "{.col}_bal").

First of all, thanks to @Iroha for the huge help. The thing was that there were compatibility and support problems when using non-tidy functions with other tidy-functions, which led me to be quite confused (ik, rookie mistake :p).
Hence, to deal with the problem. you have to call the function with do.call() and recall the columns with pick(). The code fixed would be the following:
# Example df

ind <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c(2008,2012,2016,2020)
indiv <- rep(ind, times=4)
year <- rep(y, times=3)

a <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
b <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
c <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
d <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
e <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
f <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)
g <- runif(n=12, min=0, max=100)

df_data <- data.frame(indiv,year,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

# Code for max min and new range

newdf <- df_data %>% 
  mutate(Oldmax = do.call(pmax,c(pick(a:g),na.rm=TRUE)),
         Oldmin = do.call(pmin,c(pick(a:g),na.rm=TRUE)),
         Newmax = do.call(pmax,c(pick(e:g),na.rm=TRUE)),
         Newmin = do.call(pmin,c(pick(e:g),na.rm=TRUE)),
         Oldrange = Oldmax-Oldmin,
         Newrange = Newmax-Newmin) %>% 
  mutate(across(e:g,
                (((~ .x - Oldmin) * Newrange) / Oldrange) + Newmin,
                .names = "{.col}_bal")
         )


No need to apply it in the across one though, it is supported. Check info regarding do.call() function if you do not know how it works, it can be super useful even if you do not recall it all the time (like what happened in my case).
Hope anyone dealing with this kind of problems can find it useful :)
